# Differential Equation Question: How do I solve this? $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=x$$

I've tried the substitution:
$$z=x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

But for some reason I get:
$$y=\frac{x^7}{35} + cx^2 + d$$

While the answer is supposed to be:
$$y=\frac{x^3}{3} + cx^2 + d$$

Could someone guide me on a step-by-step basis here,  because I'm clearly making a mistake at one of the steps that I'm not able to recognize.
Thanks.

Comment: I actually do use an integrating factor, but after making the substitution. Here, I'll show you my steps:
After substitution I get:
$$\frac{dz}{dx} - \frac{2z}{x} = x^2$$

Comment: Use an integrating factor. Sorry, its hard to type LaTeX using a phone.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, I'm doing the same here. I'll update my steps. give me a minute.

Comment: I actually do use an integrating factor, but after making the substitution. Here, I'll show you my steps:
After substitution I get:
$$\frac{dz}{dx} - \frac{2z}{x} = x^2$$
And the  I use the integrating factor:
$$x^2$$
Which gives me:
$$x^2\frac{dz}{dx} - 2xz = x^4$$
And after integrating on both sides:
$$\frac{z}{x^2} = \frac{x^5}{5}+c$$

Comment: Congrats! You can answer your own question with that information.

Comment: In fact, answering your own question is encouraged so that you can get the benefits of trying on your question, if you have managed to answer it.

Comment: Well, with these steps, I'm getting:
$$\frac{x^7}{35} + cx^2 + d$$ on the RHS. Any idea what mistake I'm making here?

Comment: So I think the mistake is somewhere in the last step where you wrote "And after integrating on both sides". Just check it again. I don't think $x^2$ will be the integrating factor because of the minus sign.

Comment: Ok. Let me check. I think you're right here.

Comment: Got it @Aditya, thanks for pointing it out. I'll add a solution over here soon.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Put $y' = u \implies u' - \dfrac{1}{x}u = x$. From this you can solve for $u$ and find its antiderivative to get $y$.

Comment: I realize its much more efficient than the substitution, but, my teacher wants me to solve using the substitution I mentioned. Could you check my steps and point out what I'm getting wrong? It would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You got the incorrect integrating factor. It should be $x^{-2}$ and not $x^2$. Also, the substitution you used is quite cumbersome. It should be used for a more complicated problem, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Let z=$\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dz}{dx}-\frac{z}{x}=x$

$\frac{x\frac{dz}{dx}-z}{x^2}=1$

Note that the LHS is the derivative of $\frac{z}{x}$

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{z}{x}=1$

$\frac{z}{x}=x+c'$

$z=x^2+c'x$

$y=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{c'}{2}x^2+d$

$y=\frac{x^3}{3}+cx^2+d$

Answer (score 3):

So, the integrating factor is actually:
$$e^{\int(-2/x)dx}$$
On simplifying, it gives me:
$$\frac{1}{x^2}$$
And on multiplying the integrating factor:
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dz}{dx} - \frac{2}{x^3} = 1$$
Which is: $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{z}{x^2}) = 1$$
And on integrating both sides:
$$\frac{z}{x^2} = x + c$$
$$z = x^3 + cx^2$$
Substituting back y:
$$x\frac{dy}{dx} = x^3 + cx^2$$
Which ultimately gives:
$$y = \frac{x^3}{3} + cx^2 + d$$
Thanks for your help @Wang YeFei & @Aditya

Answer (score 2):

You have $$y''-\frac{1}{x}y'=x$$
$\implies \frac{1}{x}y''-\frac{1}{x^2}y'=1$

$\implies \left( \frac{y'}{x} \right) ' =1$

$\implies \frac{y'}{x}=x+c$

$\implies y'=x^2+cx$

$\implies y=\frac{x^3}{3}+cx^2+d$.

Comment: Looks good. Its a very efficient method. My teacher however wants me to use the substitution as I mentioned in the question. Any way you could solve using that or point out an error in my steps?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ Hence $u=x+c \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+cx \implies y=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{c}{2}x^2+d$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=u$  $\implies$ $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}$

Now, put $u$ and $\frac{du}{dx}$ in equation

hence, equation become  $\frac{du}{dy}$-$\frac{u}{x}=x$

multiply by 1/x both side we get $\frac{du}{dy}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}=1$

we can write this eqn as  $\frac{d(\frac{u}{x})}{dx}=1$ $\implies $ $d(\frac{u}{x})=dx$

Integrating both side with respect to x

we get $\frac{u}{x}=x+c \implies u=x^2+cx$

Now again integrating $u$ with respect to x we get $y=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{cx^2}{2}+d$